# How istio do weight-based tcp traffic shifting?

Tags: istio

The [offical doc](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/tcp-traffic-shifting/) show a weight-based tcp traffic routing, I'm curious about how istio done this job due to tcp is streaming data, there is no delimiter in it. istio have no idea about what tcp data it will gets.

So I look into the [example code](https://github.com/istio/istio/blob/release-1.1/samples/tcp-echo/src/main.go) found the destination go server use `byte('\n')` as delimeter. Does this mean istio tcp traffic routing(exclude the port forwarding which don't need inspect the data content) require user tcp data must use '\n' as delimeter?

Comment: AFAIK it's working thanks to envoy. As mentioned [here](https://www.getambassador.io/resources/getting-started-envoyproxy-microservices-resilience/) `A listener tells Envoy a TCP port on which it should listen, and a set of filters with which Envoy should process what it hears. A cluster tells Envoy about one or more backend hosts to which Envoy can proxy incoming requests`.  And it should't require to have '\n' as delimeter. Let me know if that answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

envoy is incapable of routing custom defined L4 traffic. Its L4 traffic routing is only used for http, as the definition of http data format, string end with a `\n` is a legal [Simple-Request](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945#section-5), that's why the sample works fine.

The [custom defined filters](https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/tree/master/source/extensions/filters/network) do encode and decode in `Envoy::Networks::ReadFilter::onData` and `Envoy::Networks::WriteFilter::onWrite` respectively. However, those 2 functions pass nothing to envoy about the knowledge of packet. That means envoy can not do traffic management on those custom defined tcp stream, for example, redirect to another pod